# Access Violation Pointer Error

Tags: c++, pointers

I am implementing my version of the basic String class, however I am running into an issue that I have never seen before and have no idea how to properly debug. My code is pasted below. All functions have their header counterparts. My test is simply creating one object using the convert constructor.

```
A4String obj1("this");
```

My problem is I get an Access violation reading location exception thrown. My research has indicated that I may be trying to access memory outside of Visual Studio's allotment. I'm having trouble finding where this pointer error exists though. I have placed breakpoints through every step of the convert constructor and subsequent function calls within however my program doesn't throw the exception until it returns to main, seemingly after my program has executed completely.

```
#include "A4String.h"



A4String::A4String() {
    data = new char[5];
    data[0] = '\0';
    capacity = 5;

}

A4String::~A4String() {
    if (capacity != 0)
        delete[] data;

}
//Copy Constructor
A4String::A4String(const A4String &right) {
    cout << "copy" << endl;

    data = new char[right.capacity + 1];
    strcpy(data, right.data, capacity);
    capacity = right.capacity;

}
//Convert Constructor 
A4String::A4String(const char *sptr) {
    cout << "convert" << endl;
    capacity = (strlen(sptr)) + 1;
    data = new char[capacity + 1];
    strcpy(sptr, data, capacity);

}
//Assignment
A4String& A4String::operator = (const A4String & right) {
    //if (capacity != 0) delete[] data;
    data = new char[right.capacity + 1];
    strcpy(data, right.data, capacity);
    capacity = right.capacity;
    return *this;
}
//Equivalence
bool A4String::operator == (const A4String &right) const {
    return (strcmp(data, right.data)) == 0;

}

int A4String::length() const {
    return capacity;
}

void A4String::addChar(char) {
    //Not implemented yet
}

string A4String::toString() {
    string str = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (data[i] != '\0') {
        str += data[i];
        i++;
    }
    return str; 
}

void A4String::strcpy(const char *source, char* destination, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        destination[i] = '\0';
    int  index = 0;
    while (source[index] != '\0')
        {
        destination[index] = source[index];
        index++;
        }
    destination[index] = '\0';


}

int A4String::strcmp(char *str1,  char *str2)
{

    if (*str1 < *str2)
        return -1;

    if (*str1 > *str2)
        return 1;

    if (*str1 == '\0')
        return 0;

    return strcmp(str1 + 1, str2 + 1);

     return 0;
     }

int A4String::strlen( char *s)
{
    char *start;
    start = s;
    while (*s != 0)
    {
        ++s;
    }
    return s - start;
}
```

Comment: for debugging you can try to use valgrind: http://valgrind.org/.

Comment: @dxiv, I have an overloaded strcpy which I should prolly rename strcpy_s. Nevertheless, it compiles, plug it in if you don't believe me.

Comment: What does the class definition and your `main` look like?

Comment: There is an inconsistency about `capacity`. In the default constructor it's set to `5` i.e. the allocation size, but elsewhere it appears to be set to `1` less than the allocated size.

Comment: Main is simply creating an A4String object using convert constructor. Class def. has 2 private members, char * data, and int capacity

Comment: Asking a question like this, you shouldn't post code, which is not used (assign operator, destructor and so on) reducing code to the minimum, which reproduces the error. On the other hand it would be nice to have a complete code (header, main), so it can be easily run without the need to invent this part. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `A4String::strcpy`, the line

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    destination[i] = '\0';
```

The destination has less than 20 characters, so it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Use of the hard code number `20` in the `A4String::strcpy` is not right. I suggest changing it to `size`.

```
void A4String::strcpy(const char *source, char* destination, int size)
{
    // for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        destination[i] = '\0';
    int  index = 0;

    // Add an additional check here also.
    // while (source[index] != '\0' )
    while (source[index] != '\0' && index < size)
        {
        destination[index] = source[index];
        index++;
        }
    destination[index] = '\0';
}
```

**Disclaimer** Fixing the above function may not fix your crashing problem even though the use of `20` is most likely crashing your program. In other words, there might be other problems in your code too.